# Drupal 8 CKEditor add extra <p> tag

Tags: ckeditor, drupal-8

Drupal 8 has CKEditor as core.
CKEditor inserts extra

tag when users input "enter" (newline).
How to configure to disable this automatic paragraph tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can set auto paragraph to false. Follow this link for detailed implementation.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/253032/76694

Answer (score 0):

Use shift + enter instead of just enter. It will add a "br" instead of a new p.